# QGraphicsScene, error by accessing pointer in custom class

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, casting, qgraphicsitem

I have a pretty complex problem... In Qt I have a custom class (named FotoGebouw) that inherits from QGraphicsItem, it also contains a pointer to another custom class (named Gebouw). If I want to acces the selected items from the scene, in other words the "FotoGebouw"items, I first have to cast them to QGraphicsItems. But this way, I seem to lose the pointer (called linkGebouw) that they were pointing to.

Does anyone know a way to get the FotoGebouw items that are selected from the scene, while I can still get the

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *>bordSceneGebouwen=bordscene->selectedItems();
FotoGebouw *teVerplaatsenFoto=dynamic_cast<FotoGebouw *>(bordSceneGebouwen[0]);
Gebouw *teVerplaatsen=teVerplaatsenFoto->linkGebouw;
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your code looks fine. What means 'I seem to lose the pointer' and why is it bad?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I mean with I lose the pointer is, when those FotoGebouw classes are on the scene, their pointer is pointing to a Gebouw class. But when I get the selected Items like I do above, their pointer is set to NULL :S

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Please post some other related code.